# Auto Layout Issues Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I've been working on an app page in the iPhone 7 view of the latest version of Xcode. I got everything working and looking well and then when I went to the iPad view, everything was stretched out and looked awful. I reseted the auto layout and added different constraints and nothing will work. The bigger the screen is, the more stretched out some of the images become, while other are perfectly good. What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you setting asset catalogue for the icon 1x,2x and 3x ?

Comment: I just have 1x for all of them. No 2x or 3x.

Comment: Create 3 icons with the following sizes 1x size 29pt,2x 40pt and 3x 60pt  and import to you asset catalog and make sure your constrains setted properly..

Comment: @iap-Software Did you find a solution that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to keep the image in the middle I suggest that you don't use any of the pin constraints. Instead select the align constraints and align the image vertically/horizontally in the view.

What's happening here is that the images are pinned to the edges of the view and when you choose a wider device the images are stretched so as to maintain the pin constraints. That's not what you would want to do.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Add Aspect Ratio.connect image to view aspect ratio.next add the align constraints and align the image vertically/horizontally in the view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the `Content Mode` of your `ImageViews` to `Aspect Fit`:

[image: Content Mode]

An `Aspect Ratio Constraint` is not needed. A `Leading`, `Top` and `Center` Constraint should be enough.